# Chromecast device not playing HLS Video from iOS Application

Tags: ios, chromecast

I've registered my app and trying to cast a hls video from ios app to TV.
It works with other formats like mp4.
In the code I've mentioned the streamtype as GCKMediaStreamTypeLive and contentType as @"application/x-mpegURL".
The iOS code used is referenced from the sample app "HelloVideoGoogleCast".
And I've deployed the receiver's html file from the following sample,
https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver.

Am I missing something ?
Is there any sample app available for playing HLS video on ChromeCast device ?﻿
Why is it not playing the hls video type ?

Comment: I don't know what sample code "HelloVideoGoogleCast" you are referring to. The cast-custom-receiver has HLS content in it; follow the steps there.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the chromecast console i.e, <ChromeCastIP:9222>.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://musicvideohls.erosnow.com/hls/music/3/1005303/musicvideo/6124727/1005303_6124727_IPAD_HIGH_multi.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://tst.erosnow.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: As the error is saying, you do not have CORS headers present and set up correctly, read our documentation (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player)

Comment: Yes, CORS was the issue. Fixed it by storing the Receiver file in the same place where the content is placed.

Comment: @PradeepRajkumar in my case, sometimes the video plays on cast, sometimes it doesn't. Whereas, such issue doesn't occur in case of mp4 videos. Any idea?

Comment: @FayzaNawaz whats the error you are getting ?
Perhaps, create a separate question(add screenshots/error codes) for this issue and tag people.

Answer (score 0):

I received the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header error even when CORS headers was present and set up correctly. Turned out a simple reboot of the Chromecast device from the Chromecast iOS app fixed the issue.